# How to transfer dbo permissions with SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I have following code

```
Transfer transfer = new Transfer(sourceDatabase)
{
    DestinationServer = targetServer.Name,
    DestinationDatabase = targetDatabase.Name,

    CopyAllObjects = true,
    CopyData = true,

    Options =
    {
        DriAll = true,
        Permissions = true, // will not transfer dbo schema permissions :/
        WithDependencies = true,
        IncludeDatabaseRoleMemberships = true,
    },
    PreserveDbo = true,
    DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true
};

transfer.TransferData();
```

Transfer works fine, but I have an issue, that permissions are transfered, but not for `dbo` schema.

I also tried to set `transfer.Options.AllowSystemObjects = true` but with no help.

I don't know why is that, so I tried copy them manually

```
//  Grantor is db_owner
var databaseOwnerRole = targetDatabase.Roles["db_owner"];

// Grant dbo permissions
foreach (DatabaseRole role in sourceDatabase.Roles)
{
    // foreach (ObjectPermissionInfo permission in role.EnumObjectPermissions()) // returns null !
    foreach (ObjectPermissionInfo permission in sourceDatabase.EnumObjectPermissions(role.Name))
    {
        if (permission.ObjectSchema == "dbo" && permission.Grantee != "public")
        {
            // <targetObject?>.Grant(permission.PermissionType, permission.Grantee);
            // databaseOwnerRole.Grant(permission.PermissionType, permission.Grantee);
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't know what is proper syntax of `Grant` command, whether I grant permissions to role on some object (for example table) or I grant permissions to specific objects instead.

The `databaseOwnerRole.Grant` does not work (`grant failed`) and for the granting permissions on specific object I don't know how to retrieve this object, if I know only name (iterating all the database objects for each permission seems like a bad idea).

**Example of the issue:**

source database role

[image]

target database role after transfer is done (permissions on `dbo` schema are missing)

[image]

but on another role, the permissions setup on specific `dbo` tables are ok.

[image]

Do you have any idea, why the permission on `dbo` schema are not transferring or how to transfer them `manually` via SMO?

Comment: Have you tried with PreserveDbo = true?

Comment: Yes I tried, I am not sure what the option does, but the `dbo` schema permissions are still missing. I added additional info to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood, your issue is that the dbo schema (login name) will be set to the login in your connection string and you want it to be set to something else?

You can do this quite simply. For example if you wanted owner to be the sa login:

```
targetDatabase.SetOwner("sa");
```

Comment: Hi John, I updated my question with an example.